# Can a numpy.prod array reduction be replaced by numpy.einsum?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have an huge 8D array view that i want to reduce to 2D by multiplying the elements together over 4 axes and summing them over 2 axes. I didn´t find any example in the `numpy.einsum` documentation where the elements of the same array are multiplied with each other. The following works, but requires a lot of additional memory during computation:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((2048,2048,64,64,dtype=float32)
a[...] = data
b = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a,(3,3)+a.shape[2:],axis=(0,1,2,3))
c = np.sum(np.prod(b,axis=(2,3,4,5)),axis=(2,3))
```

Can this operation be performed by `numpy.einsum` to save memory?

Comment: You cannot multiply elements of the same array with each other using einsum. and the purpose of ```numpy.einsum``` is not to save memory. Your code is already looks good. break it into small chucks and run if you cannot fit it into memory. The memory required to create ```a```array is around 64 gb. So it is not the issue of the function.